# Django 1.8 How to filter an object by id of current generic Detail View

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-1.8

I am struggling (due to being new to django) with how to filter an object by the current details views ID.

For example, I am writing a test app that allows "venues" to have their own detail page and on that page they can display their "Menu" items, "OpeningHours" etc.

Here is what I am sending from the view to the template:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Venue
    template_name = 'nmq/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Venue.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['OpeningHours'] = OpeningHours.objects.all()
        context['Menu'] = Menu.objects.all()
        context['Venue'] = self.queryset
        return context
```

I can easily manage to get all OpeningHours from that model but this is shared across all users. I am trying to filter this by the id of the current page. I can access this on the detail page by using {{ venue.id }} but I cannot seem to manage to pull this together with anything else to just get menu items of opening hours for that particular id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `get_context_data` method for the detail view, you can access the object with `self.object`. Therefore you can `filter` with something like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['OpeningHours'] = OpeningHours.objects.filter(venue=self.object)
    context['Menu'] = Menu.objects.filter(self.object)
    return context
```

I don't think you need to set `context['Venue'] = self.queryset`. The `DetailView` allows you to access the venue with `{{ object }}` or `{{ venue }}` in the template.

Comment: Thanks so much Alasdair! I had got to the filter and had no idea where to look from there :). Any tips on which section of the documentation to learn more on this? Thanks again!

Comment: The [introduction to class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) has some examples you might find useful. Apart from that I don't have any other suggestions.